# How to answer a bash arrow selection menu through script

Tags: bash, terminal

little stuck atm with figuring out how to script an answer to a bash arrow selection menu
[image]

Basically my question is how do I script selection of an item based on name?

I do know that I can use the following command to select an option by index and this is as close as I've gotten but I think there's a way to select it by name instead

```
echo 5 | zapier link
```

Important notes:
When a version is already selected it gets the `[currently linked app]` at the end of the version, this needs to be taken into account in text search

The numbers in () i.e (142900) is important

Pretend the name that's blocked out in red is `testOver`

I would prefer not to have to install any tools to accomplish this, only use whats built into bash unless there's no other option.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a job for `expect`. Is it installed on your system?

Comment: @Socowi negative, I can install it but I would prefer not to as it needs to be ran inside a CI script so I would have to add that to docker as well

Answer (score 0):

To select a menu entry by search, you have to read zapier's output. Usally this would be a job for `expect`, but since you don't want to install anything, try the following:

```
mkfifo fifo
zapier link <fifo |
awk '/Which integration/ {m=NR}
     m && /\(142900\)/ {print NR-m; fflush(); m=0}' >fifo
rm fifo
```

This selects the option containing the string `(142900)`. Of course you can adapt the regex to select any other option. Also consider replacing `/Which integration/` by the full title of the menu to make detection safer.

If you want to see the output of zapier, use `| tee >(awk ... >fifo)`.

In case zapier behaves differently when running inside a pipe, run it inside a pseudo-terminal. If zapier buffers its output for pipes, using `script` or `stdbuf` to unbuffer the output is an absolute requirement. Otherwise the entire command may run into a deadlock.

```
script -qec './zapier link' /dev/null <fifo # on Linux
script -qe /dev/null ./zapier link <fifo    # on BSD/macOS.
```

Unfortunately, awk does not know when the menu is fully printed, so it cannot look at all the options first and then decide afterwards, but has to select one option as soon as it sees it. If there is no such option, the script gets stuck. To solve this you could replace awk with a small bash script:

```
zapier link <fifo | while IFS= read -r ln; do
  [[ "$ln" = *"Which integration"* ]] || continue
  IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -t1 -a opts
  # insert code to pick an option from the array `opts` 
  # either `echo "$((i+1))"` to select option `${opts[i]}`
  # or `break` to select no option
done >fifo
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, gonna test this today and let you know what happens, will accept this answer once I confirm it works!